# Why does the free vibration of the spring-mass system not work in actual experiment?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, friction, string, dissipation

Why do we not get free vibration of the spring mass system forever in reality?

Answer (score 2):

This is because there are always dissipative factors in the real world. For spring mass systems one of the major sources is air resistance. So rather than being purely oscillatory motion (red curve in the image) the actual motion is a decaying oscillation (green curve).

[image]

If you conduct the experiment in vacuum, there will still be a tiny rate of dissipation due to heat generated when parts of the spring rub against each other (during compression). But here the decaying envelope is very gentle. And you can see form the plot below that the actual curve *almost* follows the ideal motion for quite some time.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The oscillations eventually die out because of the damping effects of air friction, which dissipates the energy contained in the oscillating system.

If your apparatus were suspended in a vacuum, the oscillations would die out much more slowly, but in that case the friction would come from *internal friction* within the microstructure of the spring. This is far smaller than friction with the air, but it would prevent the oscillations from going on forever.